sign of singularity on legendrian arc in surface
I am learning contact geometry and the following lemma is stated in the notes of Prof. Etnyre on Convex Surfaces.
Lemma
Let $L$ be a Legendrian arc in a surface $\Sigma\subset (M,\xi)$ and $x$ a point on $L$ that is a singular point of $\Sigma_\xi$. If $\xi$ crosses $T\Sigma$ along $L$ at $x$ in a right handed way (respectively, left handed way), then $x$ is a sink (respectively, source) if it is a positive singularity and a source (respectively, sink) if it is a negative singularity.
I am having problems with the following ideas:

What does left/right handed mean? Is it true that going along the characteristic foliation turns $\xi$ in a right handed way?
How can this be true when $x$ is a positive elliptic point and we are going along $L$ in a right handed way? Surely a positive elliptic point can't be a sink. Do we assume that $L$ doesn't go through any elliptic points, only hyperbolic ones?

Remark: I'd like to understand this, since this is used in a proof showing that a surface $\Sigma$ with Legendrian boundary $\gamma$ can be isotoped to be convex iff $tw(\gamma,\Sigma)\leq0$
Update: I realize that being right/left turning is invariant of the orientation of $L$.
